# How to get value string from row table in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I want get the value of `result_status` which come from row `status`.

If value row `status` all pass the `result_status` will get value `pass` but if value row `status` one of them get `fail`. So, the `result_status` will get value `fail`.

[image]

In this picture the Result status must get value `fail` because one of them get value `fail` too

Here's the JavaScript

```
function hasil(){
  //const row =inputStat.parentElement.parentElement;
  var status = document.querySelector('[name="status_hidden[]"]').value;

  if (status !== "fail"){
    console.log("pass");
    document.querySelector("#result_status").value = 'pass';
  }else{
    console.log("fail");
    document.querySelector("#result_status").value = 'fail';
  }
}
```

Here's the AJAX

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url : "<?=site_url('c_transaksi/keranjang_method') ?>",
    data:data_method,
    success: function(data) {
        $('table#keranjang_method tbody').append(data);
        $('tfoot').show()

        $('#result_status').html('<strong>' + hasil() + '</strong>')

    },
    error: function(){
        alert('error');
    }
})
```

Here's the HTML

```
<tr class="row-keranjang-method">
        <td hidden>
            <?= $this->input->post('report_no') ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="report_no" value="<?= $this->input->post('report_no')?>">
        </td>
        <td hidden>
            <?= $this->input->post('id_testmatrix') ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="id_testmatrix_hidden[]" value="<?= $this->input->post('id_testmatrix')?>">
        </td>
        <td class="method_code">
            <p style="color:blue;"><?= $this->input->post('method_code') ?></p>
            <input type="hidden" name="method_name_hidden[]" value="<?= $this->input->post('method_name')?>">
            <p><?= $this->input->post('method_name') ?></p>
            <input type="hidden" name="method_code_hidden[]" value="<?= $this->input->post('method_code')?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <p>value from : <strong><input class="value_from" name="value_from" value="<?= $this->input->post('value_from') ?>" style="width: 4%;" disabled></strong>
            to<strong><input class="value_to" name="value_to" value="<?= $this->input->post('value_to') ?>" style="width: 4%;" disabled></strong></p>
            <p><?= $this->input->post('measurement') ?></p>
            <input type="hidden" name="measurement_hidden[]" value="<?= $this->input->post('measurement')?>">  
        </td>
        <td style="width: 10%;">
            <?= $this->input->post('result') ?>
            <input class="form-control result" type="input" name="result_hidden[]" style="align: middle;" onkeyup="sum_method(this);" value="<?= $this->input->post('result')?>">
        </td>
        <td style="width: 10%;" class="status">
            <?= $this->input->post('status') ?>
            <input class="status" type="text" name="status_hidden[]" value="<?= $this->input->post('status')?>" style="border:0; outline:0;" readonly>
        </td>
        
        <td style="width: 10%;"><center>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" id="hapus_method" data-nama-method="<?= $this->input->post('method_name')?>"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
        </td>
</tr>
```

```
<td colspan="3" align="right"><strong>Result Status : </strong></td>
                                <td id="result_status"></td>
```

But the `result_status` can't get the value.

I've tried this code, but the result can't change to pass or fail directly.

```
  $('#result_status').text($('[name="status_hidden[]"]').map((i, input) => input.value).get().sort()[0]).html('<strong>' + hitung_hasil() + '</strong>');
```

Here the result of the code above
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciS3z.png)

Comment: What does `[name="status_hidden[]"]` refer to in your HTML? Please provide sample HTML as you receive it from the ajax request, i.e. what is the value of `data`?

Comment: Hi @trincot I've already edit my HTML

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in your attempt:

- This code:

  ```
  $('#result_status').html('<strong>' + hasil() + '</strong>')
  ```

  ...expects `hasil()` to return a string, but `hasil()` has no return statement, so this will always display `undefined`
- This code in `hasil`:

  ```
  document.querySelector("#result_status").value = 'pass';
  ```

  ... displays "pass" in the result status, but this is immediately overwritten by the code mentioned in the previous point.
- This code in `hasil`:

  ```
  var status = document.querySelector('[name="status_hidden[]"]').value;
  ```

  ...only selects the first match, i.e. the status of the *first* row. You need to inspect *all* rows, not just the first one.

Correction:

A solution is to collect all statuses, and then get the minimum among them. Since "fail" is lexically less than "pass", the result will then only be "pass" if there is no "fail" in any of the rows.

Code:

```
$('#result_status').text($('[name="status_hidden[]"]')
                         .map((i, input) => input.value).get().sort()[0]);
```

(and drop `hasil`).

Comment: Hi @trincot thank you. How I put the code correction ? in the function hasil()?

Comment: Replace your `$('#result_status').html('<strong>' + hasil() + '</strong>')` with this solution. Like I wrote, drop `hasil` -- it is not needed anymore.

Comment: I've tried that code. But the result can't directly change in ```result_status``` and I've change the ```hasil``` to ```hitung_hasil``` @trincot

Comment: I don't get why you can't directly change and still want a function. But ok, if it works for you then that's what is most important.